# Increasing The Size Of The Mouse Pointer In OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to change the size of the mouse pointer to make it easier to see, as sometimes when "surfing", I find it smaller than it needs to be on the screen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Accessibility options in Preferences:

[image]